# Glossary list without page number and acronym links to glossary

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

As the title says I only wish to remove the page numbers not the acronym links to the glossary.

Using  package option nonumberlist the numbers are removed but so are the links.

This code below gives me 'CT  Computed Tomography. 1, Glossary: CT & Tomography' under Acronyms

```
\documentclass[british]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{babel} 
\usepackage[toc,acronym,style=long]{glossaries} 
\makeglossaries    
%%%%%%%%%%%Glossary%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
\newglossaryentry{ctg}{name={CT},
    description={A medical imaging technique to investigate the anatomy using x-rays}}

%%% define the acronym and use the see= option
\newglossaryentry{ct}{type=\acronymtype, name={CT}, description={Computed  Tomography},first={Computed Tomography (CT)\glsadd{ctg}}, see=[Glossary:]{ctg,tomo}} 

\newglossaryentry{tomo}{name={Tomography},
    description={Imaging by sections through an object}}    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}    

blah blah \gls{ct} blah

\glsadd{tomo}    
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]    
\printglossary[type=main]    
\end{document}
```

What I would like is 'CT  Computed Tomography. Glossary: CT & Tomography', just the page number missing.

Any Ideas?
Thanks
James

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you mean you want links from the glossary/acronym list back to the document? Without a page number, what do you want to be the link text and what should be the target?

Comment: The links to the main text are present. What I want is the acronym listed as above, with see .... but with out the page numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `see` key puts the cross-reference in the location list (this is how both `makeindex` and `xindy` behave), so if you suppress the location list (using the `nonumberlist` option) this will also suppress the cross-reference. You can use the `seeautonumberlist` package option (with `nonumberlist`) to show the location list for just the entries that have the `see` key, but you will still get the locations listed for those entries as well as the cross-reference.

Instead, I suggest you just put the cross-reference inside the description and suppress the location list with `nonumberlist`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc,acronym,style=long]{glossaries} 
\makeglossaries    

%%%%%%%%%%%Glossary%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
\newglossaryentry{ctg}{name={CT},
    description={A medical imaging technique to investigate the
anatomy using x-rays}}

%%% define the acronym 
\newglossaryentry{ct}{type=\acronymtype,
 name={CT},
 description={Computed Tomography. \emph{Glossary:} \gls{ctg}},
 first={Computed Tomography (CT)\glsadd{ctg}}} 

\newglossaryentry{tomo}{name={Tomography},
    description={Imaging by sections through an object}}    

\begin{document}    

blah blah \gls{ct} blah

\glsadd{tomo}    
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,nonumberlist]    
\printglossary[type=main]    
\end{document}
```